# Converting indices of refraction

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, estimation

If I know that the index of refraction of a given substance is $1.4$ for the average wavelength (say ${550\rm\ nm}$), and I would like to know what is the index of refraction with a wavelength of ${832\rm\ nm}$, how would I go about computing this?  I'm not looking for an exact solution, just a rough estimate that is better than $1.4$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can calculate the refractive index using an empirical formula, such as the [Sellmeier equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation). The Sellmeier coefficients are different for each material, you can find those for common materials on sites like https://refractiveindex.info/

Once you know the Sellmeier coefficients of the material, you can use [this online calculator](https://www.calctool.org/CALC/phys/optics/sellmeier).

---

**Update**

I understand from the comments that you're specifically looking for the refractive index of the crystalline lens of the eye. I found this paper: [Development of a human eye model incorporated with intraocular scattering for visual performance assessment](http://spiedigitallibrary.org/data/Journals/BIOMEDO/24714/JBO_17_7_075009.pdf), where the authors state in Equation (4a) that
$$
\begin{multline}
n(\lambda) = 1.389248 + 6.521218 \times 10^3∕\lambda^2 \\− 6.110661
\times 10^8∕\lambda^4 + 5.908191 \times 10^{13}∕\lambda^6,
\end{multline}
$$
with $\lambda$ in nm.

Answer (score 6):

You're really not going to like this. You have no choice but to find out exactly what the "substance" is and then look up dispersion curves for it. Either that or you're going to have to measure it yourself at 832nm.

In short - dispersion is not a fundamental property of matter, there is no simple law that works for all substances.

If it's a very "simple" substance (simple make up, simple crystal structure), there may be a quantum optic model it will tell you the dispersion behaviour. Otherwise it's most likely that you will have to go to an experimental curve. Optical glasses manufacturers publish detailed description of their wares' dispersion: they will usually do so as coefficients in either the Sellmeier or Schott models (these are models that have the form that arises from a series of resonances, but the coefficients are fitted experimentally).

Try also https://refractiveindex.info to see whether your "substance" is there.

If you have to resort to data from optical material manufacturers and if very high accuracy is important to you then beware of the following: optical designers define the refractive index of **AIR** AT STANDARD TEMPERATURE AND PRESSURE to be 1.0. In this definition, therefore, the vacuum has a refractive index slightly less than one. This is altogether crazy, I know, but optical designers really do mean something different from the rest of us when they say "refractive index"!

If you really stuck and you can get hold of the Abbe number for the substance, then this will give you enough data to find the coefficients in the Cauchy model:

$$n(\lambda) = A + \frac{B}{\lambda^2}$$

The Abbe number is defined by either :

$$V_D = \frac{ n_D - 1 }{ n_F - n_C }$$

where $n_D$, $n_F$ and $n_C$ are the refractive indices of the material at the wavelengths of the Fraunhofer D-, F- and C-spectral lines (589.3nm, 486.1nm and 656.3nm respectively) (more common in Japan and US) or

$$V_e = \frac{ n_e - 1 }{ n_{F^\prime} - n_{C^\prime} }$$

where $n_e$, $n_{F^\prime}$ and $n_{C^\prime}$ are the refractive indices at the green mercury e-line (546.073 nm), and blue and red cadmium lines at 480.0 nm and 643.8 nm, respectively (more common in Europe). Again, these are optical designers' refractive indices as warned above.

Comment: The substance is the crystalline lens of the eye.  Very high accuracy isn't particularly important.

Comment: Hi Tim. In that case, I think you'll need to seek help from ophthalmology-kind of people rather than physicists. Unless you can speak to groups doing things like: optical coherence tomography of the retina, or physicists concerned with laser eye surgery. I believe they need to know the refractive index for the lens at the laser wavelength so they would know what kind of models to use and what the range of the co-efficients would be. Try doing searches directed at the ophthalmology literature.

Comment: If you've met optical designers who treat the index of air as exactly 1.0, those are bad optical designers. We certainly do not do that as a general rule.

Comment: @ColinK I'm not saying literally that designers believe this - I'm saying that this is a convention built into many of the specifications for refractive indices and it is wholly historical in origin. You have to be very careful. Try calling up "Vacuum" in Zemax. It will tell you it has a refractive index $n_d = 0.99973$ and Abbe number of 89.2. If, like me, you've designed very small optics, it's not important. It's important for big telescopes and the like

Comment: @TimCooke Tim, if you're REALLY desperate, you could use the Cauchy equation fitted with the co-efficients found with the data $n(\lambda) = 1.4$ at 550nm and assuming an Abbe number of 80. This is in the neighbourhood of Abbe numbers for "normal" materials with this lowish refractive index. I don't have time to solve the equations above, but this will give you enough data.